# Load the xml string into the MVC 4 model

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I need to load the country and the corresponding state values from the xml tag CES into the MVC model . Basically the xml contains the country and state values.I need to show the country and state in two dropdown in mvc 4.0. On selecting the country on one dropdown , corresponding state values has to be shown in the another dropdown. Please help .

```
<cc>
<State>
    <MEX>
        <Record CountryCode="AE" CountryDesc="EMIRATOS ARABES UNIDOS" System="MEX" Code="UA" StateProvinceDesc="EMIRATOS ARABES UNIDOS"/>
    </MEX>
    <CES>
        <Record CountryCode="CA" CountryDesc="CANADA" System="CES" Code="AB" StateProvinceDesc="Alberta"/>
        <Record CountryCode="CA" CountryDesc="CANADA" System="CES" Code="BC" StateProvinceDesc="British Columbia"/>
        <Record CountryCode="CA" CountryDesc="CANADA" System="CES" Code="MB" StateProvinceDesc="Manitoba"/>
        <Record CountryCode="CA" CountryDesc="CANADA" System="CES" Code="NB" StateProvinceDesc="New Brunswick"/>
        <Record CountryCode="CA" CountryDesc="CANADA" System="CES" Code="NL" StateProvinceDesc="Newfoundland Labrador"/>
        <Record CountryCode="CA" CountryDesc="CANADA" System="CES" Code="NT" StateProvinceDesc="Northwest Territories"/>
        <Record CountryCode="CA" CountryDesc="CANADA" System="CES" Code="NS" StateProvinceDesc="Nova Scotia"/>
        <Record CountryCode="CA" CountryDesc="CANADA" System="CES" Code="ON" StateProvinceDesc="Ontario"/>          
    </CES>
    <MEC>

        <Record CountryCode="US" CountryDesc="USA" System="MEC" Code="WA" StateProvinceDesc="WASHINGTON"/>
        <Record CountryCode="US" CountryDesc="USA" System="MEC" Code="WV" StateProvinceDesc="WEST VIRGINIA"/>
        <Record CountryCode="US" CountryDesc="USA" System="MEC" Code="WI" StateProvinceDesc="WISCONSIN"/>
        <Record CountryCode="US" CountryDesc="USA" System="MEC" Code="WY" StateProvinceDesc="WYOMING"/>
        <Record CountryCode="US" CountryDesc="USA" System="MEC" Code="YT" StateProvinceDesc="YUKON"/>
    </MEC>
</State>
<Country>
    <MEX>           
        <Record CountryCode="VN" CountryDesc="VIETNAM" System="MEX"/>
        <Record CountryCode="YE" CountryDesc="REPUBLICA DE YEMEN" System="MEX"/>
        <Record CountryCode="YU" CountryDesc="YUGOSLAVIA" System="MEX"/>
        <Record CountryCode="ZA" CountryDesc="SUDAFRICA" System="MEX"/>
        <Record CountryCode="ZW" CountryDesc="ZIMBABWE" System="MEX"/>
    </MEX>
    <CES>

        <Record CountryCode="VI" CountryDesc="VIRGIN ISLANDS (U.S.)" System="CES"/>
        <Record CountryCode="VN" CountryDesc="VIETNAM" System="CES"/>
        <Record CountryCode="YE" CountryDesc="REPUBLIC OF YEMEN" System="CES"/>
        <Record CountryCode="YU" CountryDesc="YUGOSLAVIA" System="CES"/>
        <Record CountryCode="ZA" CountryDesc="REPUBLIC SOUTH AFRICA" System="CES"/>
        <Record CountryCode="ZR" CountryDesc="REPUBLIC OF ZAIRE" System="CES"/>
        <Record CountryCode="ZW" CountryDesc="ZIMBABWE" System="CES"/>
    </CES>
    <MEC>

        <Record CountryCode="TT" CountryDesc="TRINIDAD" System="MEC"/>
        <Record CountryCode="UK" CountryDesc="UNITED KINGDOM" System="MEC"/>
        <Record CountryCode="US" CountryDesc="USA" System="MEC"/>
        <Record CountryCode="UY" CountryDesc="URUGUAY" System="MEC"/>
        <Record CountryCode="VE" CountryDesc="VENEZUELA" System="MEC"/>
        <Record CountryCode="VI" CountryDesc="US VIRGIN ISLANDS" System="MEC"/>
    </MEC>
</Country>
```

Thanks
Sam